# Delete rows in child and parent tables in one step

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child, sql-delete

I have a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM reminder
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT r.ROWID,
                      r.id,
                      r.name,
                      r.remark,
                      u.user_id,
                      u.deadline,
                      u.audt_creation_date,
                      d.next_test_date_internal,
                      t.test_internal_external
               FROM   reminder r,
                      reminder_users u,
                      device d,
                      device_test t
               WHERE  r.id = u.reminder_id
                      AND u.receipt = 0
                      AND ( Regexp_replace(r.origin_values, '[^0-9]', '') ) = d.id
                      AND d.next_test_int_id = t.id
                      AND t.test_internal_external = 0
                      AND r.name LIKE '%Interne%'
                      AND r.name NOT LIKE '%Externe%'
                      AND u.deadline <> d.next_test_date_internal
                      AND u.deadline > SYSDATE
                      AND reminder.id = r.id
               GROUP  BY r.ROWID,
                         r.id,
                         r.name,
                         r.remark,
                         u.user_id,
                         u.deadline,
                         u.audt_creation_date,
                         d.next_test_date_internal,
                         t.test_internal_external);
```

And a second query like this:

```
DELETE FROM reminder_users
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT u.reminder_id,
                      r.name,
                      r.remark,
                      u.user_id,
                      u.deadline,
                      u.audt_creation_date,
                      d.next_test_date_internal,
                      t.test_internal_external
               FROM   reminder r,
                      reminder_users u,
                      device d,
                      device_test t
               WHERE  r.id = u.reminder_id
                      AND u.receipt = 0
                      AND ( Regexp_replace(r.origin_values, '[^0-9]', '') ) = d.id
                      AND d.next_test_int_id = t.id
                      AND t.test_internal_external = 0
                      AND r.name LIKE '%Interne%'
                      AND r.name NOT LIKE '%Externe%'
                      AND u.deadline <> d.next_test_date_internal
                      AND u.deadline > SYSDATE
                      AND reminder_users.reminder_id = u.reminder_id
               GROUP  BY u.reminder_id,
                         r.name,
                         r.remark,
                         u.user_id,
                         u.deadline,
                         u.audt_creation_date,
                         d.next_test_date_internal,
                         t.test_internal_external);
```

Table REMINDER is the parent Table, Table REMINDER_USERS contains the child records. I can not create the foreign key with cascade delete option, because only a certain set of child and parent records shall be deleted.

When I try to run the first query, i get an ora 02292-Error (ora-02292 integrity constraint violated - child record found). So in theory I would have to run the second query first in order to remove the corresponding rows in the parent table afterwards. But when I run the second query first, the select in the first query obviously returns 0 values, because I deleted the child records before.

Can somebody provide a piece of code that deletes the child records and the corresponding parent records in one step?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Perhaps switch to ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Are these `delete` statements in a PL/SQL block (or could they be)?  If so, it's easy enough to store the keys of the rows to delete in a collection and reference that in the parent delete.

Comment: @jarlh I do not want to switch to ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys, because the users are allowed to delete rows from REMINDER, but there could be rows in REMINDER_USERS which the users shall not delete.

I will try to transform the code into 'JOIN' syntax, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JustinCave: Yes, the `DELETE` statements could be part of a PL/SQL block. Could you outline the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Use logical delete, create a column in the parent table and you can make it invisible, I guess you have a foreign key in place to ensure parent-child referential integrity.

So this column will tell if the row is logically deleted on the basis of your conditions (whatever conditions you have to delete a row).
create a trigger that will be fired if the logical delete is set to 1 and this trigger will delete the row in the child table and create a second trigger which will follow your first trigger to delete the row in the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be just to do a delete in a loop.  Sure, you'd be doing row-by-row operations which generally isn't the most efficient.  But for most things, it's more than fast enough

```
for rows_to_delete in (**your select statement**)
loop
  delete from child
   where parent_id = rows_to_delete.parent_id;

  delete from parent
   where parent_id = rows_to_delete.parent_id;
end loop;
```

For more efficiency, you can do a [`delete` with a `returning into`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2761b24236cfd6f78277f959954961d).

```
create table parent (
  parent_id integer primary key,
  parent_val varchar2(10)
 );

create table child (
  child_id integer primary key,
  parent_id integer references parent( parent_id),
  child_val varchar2(10)
);

create type parent_tbl is table of integer;

declare
  l_parent_keys_to_remove parent_tbl;
begin
  delete from child
   where child_val in ('aaa', 'ccc')
   returning parent_id
       bulk collect into l_parent_keys_to_remove;
       
  delete from parent
   where parent_id member of l_parent_keys_to_remove;
end;
/
```

Or you could [`select` the rows to delete into the collection first and then use the collection for both deletes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c66f7948b922bddf7dc87907297d913)

```
declare
  l_parent_keys_to_remove parent_tbl;
begin
  select parent_id
    bulk collect into l_parent_keys_to_remove
    from parent
   where parent_val in ('a', 'c');
   
  delete from child
   where parent_id member of l_parent_keys_to_remove;
       
  delete from parent
   where parent_id member of l_parent_keys_to_remove;
end;
/
```

Note that if there are parent rows that you want to delete that may not have associated child rows, you'd want to do the `select` approach.  If you just issue the `delete` against the child table first, the `returning into` won't have values for parents that have no children.